# Android : getBridge() is returning null after capacitor 3.3.3 upgrade

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, capacitor

So based on documentation https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0

Updated capacitor to latest version 3.3.3 and removed deprecated init() method from mainAcivity.kt file but getBridge() is returning null and not able to get webview.

getBridge().webView.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface(this@MainActivity), "androidCallback")

I would appreciate any help how to get this getBridge() working so that it starts communicating with JS methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this issue was solved here https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/5328/commits and will probably be included in the next capacitor release.

Comment: no, that change has nothing to do with `getBridge()` being null

Comment: So when we add line for registerPlugin() in mainActivity file under method onCreate, and then trying to access getBridge() it returns null and app crashes. Do we need to add delay or is there any event that tells that getBridge() is ready to use?